# NGINX on Windows - No input file specified

Tags: php, nginx, webserver

I have installed NGINX web server on my Windows vServer. It's just that I can't get any further, I keep getting this message "No input file specified.".

I googled a lot but I can't get any further. I ask for help. My NGINX server is under

C: / nginx / html

I have already written a PHP.bat so that PHP works.

Domain is: habbo.manag.media

what i make false?

````
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  habbo.manag.media;
        #charset koi8-r;


        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;


        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #

        location ~* \.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }

         location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        # root   c:/Users/Kelly\ Marchewa/workspace/Code/MidAmCorp/out;

        root html;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

You've not defined your root and your server configuration.

```
root   <your absolute path to root folder goes here>;
index  index.html index.htm index.php;
```

This defines where your root folder is and what your entry point can be on your website. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I don't know what my path would be for it.  I've already tried html.  Then also C: / nginx / html only nothing worked

Comment: The path would be something like this: `c:/Users/YourUser/PhpstormProjects`